# AWS S3 404 with Ember app using history location

Tags: amazon-web-services, ember.js, amazon-s3

How do I tell AWS S3 to serve `index.html` for all pages instead of just `/`? It currently returns a 404 if I enter the app at any subroute. I'm using `history` location.

I tried both redirecting using this rule:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
    <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals >
     </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <HostName>yourdomainname.com</HostName>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

This ends in a redirect loop.

And I tried setting the error document to `index.html`. This isn't able to load static assets then because it attempts to find them at the url that was requested rather than the actual root url.

Comment: I believe this is not possible :/

Answer (score 1):

I also stumble upon this problem and as you mentioned it's not possible but there is a workaround to this problem which I used.

Instead using ember 'history' location namespace I used 'hash' location namespace and I redirected request to my hashed routes.

My redirection rules

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>403</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <HostName>bucketname-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com</HostName>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>#/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

This way If user enter url manually in browser then user is taken to right page.

Comment: Yeah, that is a solution if you don't want to use `history` location.

Comment: If you are getting a 404, HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals should be changed from 403 to 404.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the error location to index.html , no redirection rules needed

Comment: The question is from a long time ago and I don't have the ability to test this now, but I _believe_ I tried this and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CloudFront to host s3 website, which you probably should, anyways, the effective way to get rid of `404` on reload of non-index route like `www.google.com/about` or similar non `/` is by the following steps:

1. Go to your CloudFront distribution
2. Go to Error Pages
3. Create a new error page with the following params:

```
    HTTP Error Code: 404
    TTL: 0
    Custom Error Response: Yes
    Response Page Path: /index.html
    HTTP Response Code: 200
```

enjoy

credits going to this article https://gist.github.com/bradwestfall/b5b0e450015dbc9b4e56e5f398df48ff